# I have a strange issue with a data analysis freeCodeCamp project

Tags: python

So the project in question is for the data analysis certificate, it is project 4/5 page view visualizer.

Here is a link to the code on REPL: https://replit.com/@dangeloshakur/page-view-time-series-visualizer-BASICALLY-COMPLETE

So I have completed the project entirely and from what I can tell, my plots look as they should.
Not exactly the same but, the data itself looks consistent enough.

I have met and satisfied all of the test cases except one. Here is the output for it:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_bar_plot_number_of_bars (test_module.BarPlotTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/page-view-time-series-visualizer-BASICALLY-COMPLETE/test_module.py", line 63, in test_bar_plot_number_of_bars
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected, "Expected a different number of bars in bar chart.")
AssertionError: 57 != 49 : Expected a different number of bars in bar chart.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 17.809s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It seems to me that my plot is basically the same, the bars on the plot are basically the same, aside from a few cosmetic differences, which are only due to a lack of fine tuning on my part. As far as I can tell the bars in my chart are in the same number as the ones in the provided image.

This is all the code I wrote pertaining to this problem.

```py
# Import data (Make sure to parse dates. Consider setting index column to 'date'.)
df = pd.read_csv('./fcc-forum-pageviews.csv')

# Clean data
filter = df['value'].quantile([0.025, 0.975])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df[
    (df['value'] >= filter.loc[0.025]) &
    (df['value'] <= filter.loc[0.975])
]

def draw_bar_plot():
        # Copy and modify data for monthly bar plot
        # Creating the year_month column for grouping and then getting the mean values
        df_bar = df.copy()
        df_bar['year_month'] = df_bar['date'].dt.to_period('M')
        avg_views = df_bar.groupby('year_month')['value'].mean().reset_index()
    
        # Splitting year_month to year and month, so they can be interpretted separately as 'x' and 'hue' in seaborn
        # Droping the unecessary year_month column
        # Converting the month column's data into it's alphabetic counter parts
        avg_views[['year', 'month']] = avg_views['year_month'].astype(str).str.split('-', expand = True)
        avg_views = avg_views.drop('year_month', axis = 1)
        avg_views['month'] = avg_views['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[int(x)])

        # hue_order is so that the months will display from jan-dec, 
        # instead of starting with the first month in the dataset which is May.
        hue_order = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1, 13)]
        
        # Draw bar plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.barplot(
            data = avg_views,
            x = 'year', y = 'value', hue = 'month', 
            palette = sns.color_palette(),
            hue_order = hue_order
        )
        plt.legend(title = 'Months')
        ax.set_xlabel('Years')
        ax.set_ylabel('Average Page Views')
        plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
        plt.tight_layout()
        
        # Save image and return fig (don't change this part)
        fig.savefig('bar_plot.png')
        return fig
```